# Google Cloud SQL Import 2005 backup FAILS

Tags: sql, sql-server, google-cloud-sql

I got a backup of MS SQL 2005 Database from a customer. I am trying to use Google Cloud SQL (2017) to view the database. I put the backup on Google cloud storage bucket, and when I try to IMPORT the Database (20GB) I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.sql.operations.wait) [ERROR_SQL_SERVER_EXTERNAL_WARNING] 90 is not a supported compatibility level. Supported: [140, 130, 120, 110, 100]
```

I know that this has to do with the old version of the source backup, but I want to view the database, however, Google Cloud SQL is FAILING....

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. 2005 databases can only be restored on 2005-2012 instances; (extended) support for SQL Server 2005 ended a long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, the error is telling you the problem; you can't restore a database from a SQL Server 2005 instance on a instance running SQL Server 2017. Support for SQL Server 2005 ended a long time ago, and newer versions will not allow you to `RESTORE` a database from such an old version as they lack the ability to run the database in the needed compatibility mode.

To `RESTORE` a copy of a database from a SQL Server 2005 instance you will first need to find and install either SQL Server 2008 or 2012 (2008 is also completely out of support, so I recommend 2012). Due to the size of the database, this will not be allowed to be Express. Developer edition for both these versions was not free, and if you can find them, I doubt they will be now.

Once you have a 2008/2012 instance installed you will need to `RESTORE` the database on the instance, and then update the compatibility level to the latest version (100 for 2008, 110 for 2012). Then you'll need to `BACKUP` that database.

Finally, once you have made a `BACKUP` of the database from 2008/2012, with it's new compatibility level, you can `RESTORE` that backup on your 2017 instance.